# Getting OperationalError: no such function: version when running syncdb for the first time

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-migrations

I'm setting up a new environment for an existing Django codebase. However, I am unfortunately unable to successfully complete a `./manage.py syncdb` or a `./managage.py migrate`. Here is my error output, including full traceback:

```
./manage.py syncdb
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: djcelery, rest_framework_swagger, django_extensions, taggit_serializer, djrill, rest_framework, staticfiles, django_jinja, _humanize, messages, flat, corsheaders
  Apply all migrations: contenttypes, taggit, push, auth, admin, djmail, plug, site, sessions, kombu_transport_django, user, core, grid
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying user.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 316, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: version

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 25, in handle
    call_command("migrate", **options)
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 222, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 148, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 59, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 236, in create_model
    definition, extra_params = self.column_sql(model, field)
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 135, in column_sql
    db_params = field.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 625, in db_parameters
    type_string = self.db_type(connection)
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_pgjson/fields.py", line 51, in db_type
    if get_version(connection) < 90200:
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/version.py", line 43, in get_version
    cursor.execute("SELECT version()")
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 658, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/Users/jamesrasmussen/.virtualenvs/honey-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 316, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such function: version
```

Other information:
Django version: `1.8.4`
Python version: `3.5.1`

My database settings:

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

I have tried to find in Django where any `version()` function is being called, but with no success. I have also tried to fiddle with my SQLite3 version on OSX, but have been wary to change the default system version. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you write your `settings.py` file, please?

Comment: @VíctorM updated the question to include my database settings. If you need my whole settings file, a sanitized version of it is here: https://dpaste.de/bmdE

Comment: What version of django did the existing codebase use?

Comment: In my `requirements.txt` file: `Django==1.8.4`. All versions using `1.8.4`

Comment: @JamesRasmussen what I am not understanding is why django is calling the function get_version() from the module postgresql_psycopg2

Comment: @VíctorM I just answered my question. I believe I figured it out. My conjecture is there's some requirement for Postgres' `get_version()` when Django runs my migration files, though I don't know where and haven't looked enough at Django's migration source to know if that's the case. At any rate, thanks for helping me realize there was a Postgres call in that stack trace, as I would have never searched my codebase for `postgres` and found that `local.example.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I feel rather foolish because I don't *totally* understand what is happening, and this answer is very specific to my environment and rather useless to others, but I did get it to work by doing the following:

I realized that my `.gitignore` file has an entry for `settings/local.py`. I checked, and don't have a `local.py` file, but I do have a `local.example.py` file. So, I copied that file into a `local.py` example, and saw that it was indeed using `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2` as its database backend. I think that somewhere in the project's migration files, there was a specific call for Postgres' `get_version()` function happening. Now that I've installed Postgres and created a database for this project, the syncdb command worked flawlessly.

My database settings now:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": "honey-api",
    }
}
```

Sorry to send all that helped me on a wild goose chase. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

On a past project I have seen django (south) migrations which executed hand-crafted SQL - when those migrations contain db vendor specific code, they cannot be run against another db backend. So first I would check the content of the failing migration file to confirm or exclude this possibility.